# PHP array_combine is not returning all the values

Tags: php, arrays

I am reading from the excel file two columns. One contains old ids and the other one returns new ids. So I am having two arrays:

```
$newAttributeIDs and $oldAttributeIDs
```

If I do count of each array separatly, I will get this result:

```
var_dump(count($newAttributeIDs)); // result is 3440
var_dump(count($oldAttributeIDs)); // result is 3440
```

And I would like to have key value pair of this values, but when I do:

```
$keyValueNewOldAttributeIDs = array_combine($oldAttributeIDs, $newAttributeIDs);
```

And then:

```
var_dump(count($keyValueNewOldAttributeIDs)); // result is 1990
```

I am getting wrong result, and some ids are now missing in the $keyValueNewOldAttributeIDs array.
Does anyone knows what is causing this? Thanks!

Comment: Are all the values in $oldAttributeIDs unique?

Comment: No, I just checked, I did var_dump(count(array_unique($oldAttributeIDs))); and it returned 1990.

Comment: There you go then. You can't have an array with duplicate keys.

Comment: array_merge will not return key, value pair of the two arrays.

Comment: @user2450639 Show the arrays you have(just a sample) and your expected output. Then we can tell you what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this flipping the values. Since I had some of the same values in the $oldAttributeIDs, result was unexpected. First value should have all unique values in the array. I missed that fact.